# IE 11 - Can not solve "Object doesn't support property or method 'charCodeAt'" OR "Object doesn't support property or method 'readAsBinaryString'"

Tags: internet-explorer, binary, cross-browser, blob, compatibility

I am using xlsx.core.min.js to upload excel files to SP and pass their contents to a new list. I have it working in Edge but it will not work in IE 11.

The first console error I received was **"Object doesn't support property or method 'charCodeAt'"**

I read about the compatibility issues with .readAsArrayBuffer() and replaced it. Then I started receiving the error **"Object doesn't support property or method 'readAsBinaryString'"**

**note: using only .readAsArrayBuffer() resulted in the original 'charCodeAt' console error **

How can I get this code working? Thank you in advance!

```
function ExportToTable() {
            var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9\s_\\.\-:])+(.xlsx|.xls)$/;
            /*Checks whether the file is a valid excel file*/
            if (regex.test($("#excelfile").val().toLowerCase())) {
                var xlsxflag = false; 
     /*Flag for checking whether excel is .xls format or .xlsx format*/
            if ($("#excelfile").val().toLowerCase().indexOf(".xlsx") > 0) {
            xlsxflag = true;
        }
        /*Checks whether the browser supports HTML5*/
        if (typeof (FileReader) != "undefined") {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function (e) {
                var data = e.target.result;
                /*Converts the excel data in to object*/
                if (xlsxflag) {
                    var workbook = XLSX.read(data, { type: 'binary' });
                }
                else {
                    var workbook = XLS.read(data, { type: 'binary' });
                }
                /*Gets all the sheetnames of excel in to a variable*/
                var sheet_name_list = workbook.SheetNames;

                var cnt = 0; /*This is used for restricting the script to consider only first sheet of excel*/
                sheet_name_list.forEach(function (y) { /*Iterate through all sheets*/
                    /*Convert the cell value to Json*/
                    if (xlsxflag) {
                        var exceljson = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(workbook.Sheets[y]);
                    }
                    else {
                        var exceljson = XLS.utils.sheet_to_row_object_array(workbook.Sheets[y]);
                    }
                    //alert (exceljson.length + " ----" + cnt);
                    if (exceljson.length > 0 && cnt == 0) {
                        BindTable(exceljson, '#exceltable');
                        cnt++;
                    }
                });
                $('#exceltable').show();
            }
            if (xlsxflag) {/*If excel file is .xlsx extension than creates a Array Buffer from excel*/
                reader.readAsArrayBuffer($("#excelfile")[0].files[0]);
            }
            else {
                reader.readAsBinaryString($("#excelfile")[0].files[0]);
            }
        }
        else {
           // alert("Sorry! Your browser does not support HTML5!");
       }
    }
    else {
       // alert("Please upload a valid Excel file!");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to refer to the following code to read the **.xlsx file**.

```
document.getElementById('file-object').addEventListener("change", function(e) {
  var files = e.target.files,file;
  if (!files || files.length == 0) return;
  file = files[0];
  var fileReader = new FileReader();
  fileReader.onload = function (e) {
    var filename = file.name;
    // pre-process data
    var binary = "";
    var bytes = new Uint8Array(e.target.result);
    var length = bytes.byteLength;
    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      binary += String.fromCharCode(bytes[i]);
    }
    // call 'xlsx' to read the file
    var oFile = XLSX.read(binary, {type: 'binary', cellDates:true, cellStyles:true});
  };
  fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
});
```

More details, please check [this article](https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx/wiki/Reading-XLSX-from-FileReader.readAsArrayBuffer()).

Comment: would I replace my code with this or would I add this in as a polyfill? Please send a full answer

Comment: The above code is used to read .xlsx file, if you want to create an array buffer when upload .xlsx file, you could use it.